# TFS - Adding Solution to Team Project - Some files not included in Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a strange one.

I have created a new Team Project using Visual Studio 2015 (with TFS 2015). I then need to create a solution out of a legacy web site (as the original solution no longer exists - just the published web files) then I need to add this newly compiled solution into the new Team Project.

All goes well and it seems as though it has worked according to plan - but when I then go to another machine, get the latest version of the solution there are a few files that are missing.

When I then go back to my project where I added the solution from (with the original source files) I can see that the missing files are there - but they do not have the blue padlock suggesting it is in Source Control.

[image]

Stranger still... right clicking the file and the menu items that appear suggests that the file IS in Source control!

[image]

I basically want to know if there are any reasons why files within a solution/web project will not get included in Source control?

Comment: It's been a while since I used TFS, but as I recall TFS will "helpfully" ignore certain files when importing a project into source control because it identifies them as being non-source files.  You can check this by actually looking at the tree within TFS-- are the files there?  If they are not, you can work around the exclusion by adding the files manually, perhaps from the command line.

Comment: Are you able to build the project with latest version on another machine?

Comment: If a different machine downloads the project from TFS these files were not being included. However, I was able to add the files to Source Control using Developer Command Prompt and this seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get these files into Source Control using Developer Command Prompt. This was simple...

1) Copy the files to the locations they should be (if they are not already there).

2) Load Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio and browse to the folder location where these files should be.

3) Execute the following ***tf add file.dll***

4) the file should be added to Source Control and will be there to load in Pending Changes

It worked for me!